# Could anyone please identify this Indian bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Photographed by a friend recently in central India. next to Panna Tiger Reserve.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please edit your post to add an estimate for the size of this insect as that can be a helpful clue for identifications. ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: While I can't help with a specific identification, it looks to me to be some sort of immature true bug whose wings are still coming in.  That may help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not see it and there is only this one photo. Such amazing markings caught my eye. Was thinking assassin but could find no exact image. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Joanna if you think my answer is right please select it as the answer. Also,@cowrie try narrowing down the species with the geographic location too, helps a lot:)

Comment: @Joanna please mark my answer as verified if you find it accurate

Answer (score 4):

The species from the photo is almost definitely a ***Catamiarus brevipennis***.
[image: A HighRes Picture]

- The bulged and striped abdomen
- The non-striped legs
- The unique pattern on the wings
- The antenna thick at the beginning and becomes thinner towards the end.
- The protonum also has a unique granular structure unique to ***Catamiarus brevipennis***.

Source : [*India Biodiversity Portal*](https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/276140)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a hemipteran, an assasin bug. I think this because of the shape of the legs, the reduced elytra and the bulgy eyes. If you had a picture from the side which would show the profile of the mouthparts, and if they happened to be protruding in the shape of a stylet, i'd be more confident that it is a type of assasin bug. Its definitely trying to mimic some other insect - hope this helps!